# Corrupted SQLite Database jpegs?

Tags: python, sqlite, blob

I am trying to take BLOB type information from rows in a sqlite database and save them into picture files. They are all jpg files stored in the blob. When I attempt to loop through and create my jpeg files from the database blobs I get strange corrupted looking jpeg files that have some of the original data and shows the image, but there is alot of distortion too. I think it has to do something with the way the data is being handled from the DB. Anyways it's column six that contains the blobs, here is my code...

```
import sqlite3
cnt = 0
con = None
con = sqlite3.connect("C:\\my.db")
cur = con.cursor()
data = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM friends")
for item in data:
    cnt = cnt + 1
    a = open("C:\\images\\"+str(cnt)+".jpg", 'w')
    a.write(item[6])
    a.close()
```

It will create an image for each blob in each row, 902 to be exact, and the images actually are viewable, even of the correct picture, just some heavy distortion/corruption has been added and really mucks up the pictures? How can I create jpg picture files from each blob jpg file in my database using Python that aren't corrupted?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not a great method, but all JPG files start with `\xFF\xD8` and end `\xFF\xD9`.  You could take everything inside of that and hope it's a valid JPG image.

Comment: @GigaWatt yOyA :D I once made a carving program for jpegs that worked off of similar signatures, was pretty fun! Thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write files in binary mode: `open("C:\\images\\"+str(cnt)+".jpg", 'wb')`.